# Undetected_chromedriver + Seleniumwire together

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver, seleniumwire

I used to work with "seleniumwire" because I was comfortable getting "requests" from "driver". Now the situation has changed and I need to use "undetected_chromedriver", but as you know, this library does not support "requests" at the moment.

I know that "seleniumwire" also has an "undetected_chromedriver" option, but for some reason, it detect me as a bot (captcha).

Short example for that.

Bad:

```
from time import sleep
import seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = uc.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.nowsecure.nl")
    sleep(5)
    print(driver.title)
```

Good:

```
from time import sleep
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = uc.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.nowsecure.nl")
    sleep(5)
    print(driver.title)
```

Is it possible to still get Requests using "undetected_chromedriver"?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by `it doesn't work as "fully" `

Comment: @kaliiiiiiiii If you run the code I attached, you'll know what I'm talking about. seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver.v2 is recognized by the detectors.

Comment: Allright, why using `.v2` then?

Comment: @kaliiiiiiiii Haha, have you worked with these libraries or are you just asking questions? :D I use .v2, cause I need it :)

Comment: I did, also author of Selenium-Profiles btw. But , maybe `seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver.v2` is deprecated?

Comment: Using a French VPN IP makes me pass the test without capcha. Yes; `undetected_chomerdriver` looks deprecated, better use `stealth` plugin

Comment: @GillesQuénot 
I don't quite understand how you found this deprecated. However, I tried to do the same with the regular version of "seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver" and that didn't work either. Strange, I have a German IP and the code I gave above doesn't work for me. More specifically, the "undetected_chromedrive" part doesn't work. Can you tell me more about this plugin?

Comment: @kaliiiiiiiii Sorry I didn't look at your profile, your question seemed strange to me because I didn't know that this library was deprecated.

Comment: @fer0m I only meant that `.v2` is deprecated. undetected-chromedriver itsself is maintained. Also, stealth has some issues with getting detected. I assume you get detected with seleniumwire, because the proxy changes ssl